# Wrtie ByteArrayOutputStream to Html5 video failed in Chrome (Java Servlet)

Tags: java, google-chrome, servlets, html5-video, bytearrayoutputstream

I have a video tag in jsp, the src is the url to servlet.

```
<video src="/MyApp/video" controls="true"></video>
```

Here is the corresponding servlet

```
public class VideoServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        go(req, resp);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }

    private void go(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("/Users/me/video.mp4");
        int fileSize = (int) file.length();
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4096);
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            final byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 8];
            for (int v; (v = inputStream.read(buf)) >= 0;) {
                if (v > 0)
                    outputStream.write(buf, 0, v);
            }

            response.setHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
            response.setContentType("video/mp4");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_PARTIAL_CONTENT);
            response.setContentLength(fileSize);
            response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + 0 + "-" + fileSize + "/" + fileSize);

            outputStream.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I use Firefox, it works, I can play the video after page loaded, but in Chrome, I got EofException (jetty) or ClientAbortException (tomcat).

Here is the exception stack trace when using jetty:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:786)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:530)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:167)
    at VideoServlet.go(VideoServlet.java:56)
    at VideoServlet.doGet(VideoServlet.java:25)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:833)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1637)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:597)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:270)
    ... 49 more
```

Is my usage wrong or maybe it is a browser issue?

If it's my usage wrong, how should I write ByteArrayOutputStream to browser to play the video?

Comment: That error is unrelated to your usage of ByteArrayOutputStream (which is also unnecessary and a waste of memory - you can directly copy the file's InputStream to the OutputStream of the servlet response). It's probably because you pretend to support ranges, but you totally ignore the range request sent by the client. Likely you tricked Chrome into thinking that you support ranges.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the document, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.2.

A Content-Range field value is invalid if it contains a byte-range-resp that has a last-byte-pos value less than its first-byte-pos value, or a complete-length value less than or equal to its last-byte-pos value.

So I changed

```
response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + 0 + "-" + fileSize + "/" + fileSize);
```

to

```
response.setHeader("Content-Range", "bytes " + 0 + "-" + (fileSize - 1) + "/" + fileSize);
```

It works in Chrome now.